# connecting to remote websphere mq from Spring java client

Tags: spring, ibm-mq, jndi

Recently I encountered problem of connecting to remote websphere MQ server. However I am able to connect with MQJExplorer successfully.

[image: MQJ EXplorer]

When I put same config in Spring java client it throws below exception

***MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'***

Spring context

```
<bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">          
    <property name="environment">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">hostname:1414/SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.authentication">simple</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">username</prop>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">password</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: What username is being passed via MQJExplorer vs your Spring app?  The 2035 means that MQ said that the user it resolved was not authorized.  Can you look at the queue managers AMQERR01.LOG to see what permission error it complained of?  What version of MQ are you using on the queue manager and what version of MQ are the jar files from?

Comment: @JoshMc username/pwd is same in both the places . I will check on logs and jars and come back. Thanks